# Conventional workflow to build deployable maven code from repo

Tags: java, maven, deployment, build

I am setting up a Maven repository with the goal of automating much of my build and deploy process.  My current workflow begins with bringing up a server, doing a `git clone`, and running a bunch of `mvn install` commands to complete the top level application.

To my understanding, Maven is not a tool for deploying applications, and at this point I do not see a need for a continuous integration or continuous deployment server or formal process.

However, thus far I have not been able to find a canonical way to put together the complete, runnable program together with Maven.

This script goes so far as to get the top level jar and install it into the local maven repo:

```
mvn -DgroupId=me.company -DartifactId=Top-Level-Application -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT   -DrepoUrl='http://theserver:8081/nexus/' dependency:get
```

If I installed everything manually, this application would find all of its dependent jars in a `lib/` directory, as Maven ought to do.  However this jar as pulled is not deployable - while the dependent jars are installed to a local repo they are not compiled where the classpath expects it.

I imagine if I could rig the above script to pull the `pom.xml` instead of just the jar and run a `mvn install` on that, everything would go smoothly (although weirdly that seems to be duplicating the last step of the build process).  Another option is for applications to contain all dependent jars rolled up into one giant jar and have no external dependencies.

Which of these (or other) options is the proper way to complete the Maven build process?

Here is our top-level pom narrowed down to as much as I can think would be relevant:

```
<project>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>me.company</groupId>
<artifactId>Top-Level-Application</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Top Level Application</name>
<url>http://company.me</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>releases</id>
        <url>http://host:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <name>Internal Snapshots</name>
        <url>http://host:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>me.company.application.MainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>
                            ${project.build.directory}/lib
                        </outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>me.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>First-Library</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- more in-house libraries -->
    <!-- third party libraries - Apache Commons, javamail, etc. -->
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Describing the structure of your application, it's packaging and the target deploy environment, would go a long way in helping us help you.

Comment: @Perception included pom

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong -- you want to transform your source code into a compiled JAR, with appropriately-set classpath for its dependencies? That's not what `dependency:get` is for at all. You should look into the [Maven JAR plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/) and/or the [Maven AppAssembler](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/) plugin.